# How do you link info from other tables in ms-access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm doing a mail merge from an Access Database. Most of the fields are coming from one table, but I have one field which lists an assigned person to a contact. I want to display that assigned persons contact info–which is in a separate table–to display in the merge.

Is there a way I can populate that assigned person field with a reference, or link to the record in the second table?

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a select query that joins the two tables on the person id.

This is so basic that it sounds like you really need to study some intro tutorials for relational databases.

Comment: Today is my first day using access, I would love it if you could recommend a tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, no, but just search on the topic. Plenty are to be found. Or study Amazon if you are prepared to spend some money.